# Unit Separator "us"

Tags: unicode, ascii, special-characters, delimiter, utf

I've seen the unit separator represented as different symbols (I've provided links to each one). What's the difference between each one? I'm working on a project and the only symbol that works is the "us" symbol.

Unit Separator Symbol #1: [image: Unit Separator Symbol #1]

Unit Separator Symbol #2: [image: Unit Separator Symbol #2]

Unit Separator Symbol #3: [image: Unit Separator Symbol #3]

Comment: Unit separator is from olden times. For example, see [asciitable.com](https://www.asciitable.com/) for other *control characters* that were in common use. What is your use for the unit separator, and does it need a visual representation?

Comment: The first link you provided isn't a Unit Separator (U+001F), it's Replacement Character (U+FFFD), which is what some UTF (often UTF-8) decoders use to indicate that the bytes are invalid. Why do you believe the first link is US? (Why do you need US? As Andrew notes it is incredibly unusual in modern formats. I don't know of any current data format that uses it. And by "modern" here I mean "since the 1970s.")

Comment: the first one is a [replacement character U+FFFD �](http://www.unicode-symbol.com/u/FFFD.html) which is shown when the font renderer has no font to render it or the character stream is broken. It has nothing to do with the unit separator

Answer (score 0):

Unit separator is one of the many ASCII control codes, so done for very old times. You see that you can use FS, GS, RS, and US, to split data (e.g. on a serial console).

Such control characters are interpreted as control character in Unicode (so in modern world), so without a real symbol.

And then things may get complex. Text processor, shaping engines and/or fonts may interpret control characters differently: either just as control, and so possibly ignoring them, if they do not have semantic for such control, or trying to display it. One common form it is to use U+241F (SYMBOL FOR UNIT SEPARATOR), in the Unicode block *Control Pictures* (U+2400 – U+243F), which includes symbols for all ASCII control codes. Note: fonts display it differently, some fonts as a boxed text with an abbreviation, some fonts as small letters in diagonal.

Note old fonts (with 256 symbols) used control character for extra symbols, see e.g. the default DOS code page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437, where you see your symbol: the black triangle. ("Black" in font means *filled*, so not just the sides/contour). Note: there were also special methods on how to print them (instead of interpreting them as control characters), and different systems used different symbols on control codes.